# where is postgres database stored on hard disk

Tags: database, postgresql

i want to hand in a course work for marking but i have no idea what files represent the database.
**Question:**
Where can i find the postgres sql database on my hard disk?
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use [pg_dump](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/app-pgdump.html) to export the database to SQL. Giving the raw files won't work if they are running a different version, 64bit instead of 32bit or something else in the environment.

You can easily export it using [pgadmin3](http://www.pgadmin.org/)

Answer (score 4):

Checkout the startup parameter -D for the Postgres service. It defines where the data directory is located.

Edit: 
To hand in your homework, you'd better export the database using pg_dump as WoLpH suggested. The actual files in the data directory are binary files and I bet your teacher want's to have SQL scripts

Answer (score 2):

The database files are in what is called the "data" directory. Depending on your environment there are a few ways to tell - here is one that should work everywhere:

psql -d database_name_here -c "show data_directory"

And if you're turning this in for some school work you should:

pg_dump -d database_name_here

Answer (score 0):

If installed by `apt-get` or similar package manager, most likely in

```
/usr/local/pgsql/data
```